# What is the minimum time for the 3 boys to get to this one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization

Alice, Bob and Charlie go to a party located 75 km from their home. Alice has an old motorcycle, with 2 places available (including her place) that can reach 30 km / h. Bob can run at 10 km / h and Charlie can walk at 6 km / h. To get to the party Alice takes Charlie on her motorcycle from her house for a distance d ≤ 75 and then returns for Bob to take her to the party. What is the minimum time for the 3 boys to get to this one?

So, I've solved this problem but I'm not sure of the answer, so I will put my solution, please, share with me if I am wrong or if i am right

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: The changing names is unhelpful and confusing.  Just call the people $A,B,C$.    Seems natural to imagine that, in the optimal strategy, all three arrive at the party at the same instant.  That should determine the answer.

Comment: It is not necessary that they arrive at the same time, and you are right I should use A, B and C as names jaja, it's more natural

Comment: Yes, it is necessary.  The time it takes all $3$ to reach is the maximum of the time it takes C and the time it takes the pair $AB$.  As these are lines,  one will decrease from the intersection, and the other will increase...hence the min occurs at the intersection.

Comment: But they are conditioned by the velocity

Comment: I don't understand.  Suppose that $C$ arrives ahead of the others.  Then $A$ could have dropped $C$ off earlier and sped the process up.  Similarly, if $C$ arrived later then $A$ should have dropped $C$ off later.  Thus, at the minimum, they all arrive together.

Comment: The problem specifies a certain order of arrival, It's said that aA must lead to  C first in her motorcycle

Comment: No.  The problem specifies a process.  $A$ takes $C$ to point $P$, after which $C$ walks the rest of the way, while $A$ goes back to pick $B$ up.  If $P$ is near the party then $C$ will arrive first.  If $C$ is far from the party, $A,B$ will arrive first.  For one choice of $P$ they will all arrive together.  That's the minimum.

Comment: I got it, so, could the problem be solved with a system of equtions?

Comment: Yes, by following the hint I have given you.  Pick a point $P$ some unknown distance from the start and work out the time of $C's$ arrival, and the time of $AB's$ arrival.  Set them equal to solve the problem.